# CSS counters with specific numbering

Tags: css

How can i create a single or multiple CSS counters to imitate the numbering in the screenshot below? Still learning on counters and this numbering format is killing me. Thanks in advance!

[Ordered List with custom numbering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRSwx.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may do this easily with two or more counters.

Steps:

1. Reset first level counter in `body` using attribute `counter-reset`
2. Reset the second level counter in the style declaration of the first level element (`h1`)
3. Reset the third level counter in the style declaration of the second level element (`h2`) and so on
4. Use `::before` selector in each level to increment the corresponding counter and put the `content` as desired by using `counter()` function

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Context</h1>
<h2>HTML</h2>
<h2>Javascript</h2>

<h1>Details</h1>
<h2>HTML</h2>
<h2>Javascript</h2>

<h1>Conclusion</h1>
```